# Is it possible to create a type that recursively enforce values?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider this data structure :

```
const routes = {
  root: '/',
  foo: '/foo',         //ok
  bar: {
    root:'/bar',
    foo: '/bar/foo',   // ok 
    bar: '/bar/:barId',// ok
    baz: '/baz'        // should ko
  },
} as const;
```

Is it possible to write a type that would enforce the values inheriting from the parent & local root property  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you can achieve this with a conditional mapped type and template literals:

```js
interface Root {
    root: string;
}

type Routes<T extends Root> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends "root"
        ? T[P]
        :  P extends string
            ? T[P] extends Root
                ? T[P]["root"] extends `${T["root"]}${P}`
                    ? Routes<T[P]>
                    : never
                : `${T["root"]}${string}`
            : never;
};
```

Here is an annotated version of `Routes` to help explain how it works:

```js
// For any object that has a "root" key that is a `string`
type Routes<T extends Root> = {
  // For each key in the object
  [P in keyof T]:
    // If the key is the "root" key
    P extends "root"
      // then its type is whatever it originally was (which is `string`)
      ? T[P]
      // otherwise if the key is a string other than "root"
      : P extends string
        // and if the key's value is an object that also has a "root" key that's a `string`
        ? T[P] extends Root 
          // and if the value of that object's "root" key begins with the value of the current object's "root" key + the name of the key we're currently examining
          ? T[P]["root"] extends `${T["root"]}${P}`
            // then the sub-object is itself a `Routes`
            ? Routes<T[P]>
            // otherwise it is an object in a different form that we don't allow
            : never
          // and if it wasn't an object, then it must be a `string` that begins with the value of the current object's "root" key
          : `${T["root"]}${string}`
        // otherwise the key we were examining couldn't be coerced into a string (e.g. a symbol)
        : never;
};
```

Examples to demonstrate that it works:

```js
// This is a valid `Routes`.
const one = {
    root: "/",
    foo: "/foo",
    bar: "/bar",
} as const;

// This is not a valid `Routes` because `two.bar.baz` doesn't begin with "/bar".
const two = {
    root: "/",
    foo: "/foo",
    bar: {
        root: "/bar",
        foo: "/bar/foo",
        bar: "/bar/:barId",
        baz: "/baz",
    },
} as const;

// This is not a valid `Routes` because `three.bar.root` is not "/bar".
const three = {
    root: "/",
    foo: "/foo",
    bar: {
        root: "qux",
        foo: "qux/foo",
        bar: "qux/:barId",
        baz: "qux",
    },
} as const;

const oneRoutes: Routes<typeof one> = one;
const twoRoutes: Routes<typeof two> = two;
const threeRoutes: Routes<typeof three> = three;
```

In this example, the assignment of `oneRoutes` will be accepted by the compiler, but the assignments of `twoRoutes` and `threeRoutes` will produce errors. See the linked TS Playground below to read the full error.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=3&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHt1mQbwLABQyxyUmYAXMgM5hSgDmA3IQL6GFgCeADihgFdI1ADwAVZBAAekEABNqacgD5kAXlyESyANoAFZKGQBrCF3QxkYgLpUD02QuQAiMlmdbtJAPxX91zy9kKmR7GQh5RVp6EAZAoJ8-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-YaMqiMkTcPgWW8QVQaAHbG96+9KEuiM+ECvnqH7IHq35dtg1a1n+j5ASBPa1mBMEQEwQA)